# selfpointer inside template friend function

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, friend-function

How can I get pointer to object in friend function?

def.h

```
class A
{
public:
     template <typename some_type_t>
     friend void foo(some_type_t &val);

     A();
     virtual ~A();    
private:
     int x;
     inline A* GetSelfPtr(){return this;}
};

class B
{
public:
      template <typename some_type_t>
      friend void foo(some_type_t &val);

      B();
      virtual ~B();    
private:
      int x;
      inline B* GetSelfPtr(){return this;} 
};
#include "templt.h"
```

templt.h

```
template <typename some_type_t>
void foo(some_type_t &val)
{
     GetSelfPtr()->x;
}
```

error: there are no arguments to ‘GetReqPtr’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘GetReqPtr’ must be available [-fpermissive]

Comment: Which self do you want? The function is a friend of the whole class, to call a method you still need an instance that has to come from somewhere

Comment: `GetSelfPtr()` is a method. not a function. is is private. it is not called on an object. Does this point you in a direction?

Comment: Do you want `template <typename T> friend void foo(B& b, T&val);` instead ?

Comment: Btw, your `template <some_type_t>` is invalid, `typename` is missing.

Comment: I don't want to do add foo() in every class.

Comment: smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is `foo` actually supposed to be good for? Btw I guess you meant you want to add foo to every class but not type the code for every class?!?

Comment: Are you looking for `val.GetSelfPtr()->x`?